How to fill in a RF dead zone with GMRS?
I live in a community with lots of terrain features.  Our local emergency group has a GMRS repeater in a centralized location that is able to reach about 90% of the area with excellent coverage, according to modeling by Radio Mobile and confirmed with on-the-ground testing.
Despite the relatively excellent coverage, there remains a particular street that is in a particularly deep valley that is angled away from the repeater, resulting in the entire street being an RF dead zone.  My objective is to allow effective duplexed radio communications on GMRS on this street.
I am assuming that linking GMRS repeaters is not an option, now that the FCC has clarified their language around linking, so I am looking for alternatives.
A few options that have come up include:

Set up a billboard-style passive repeater to reflect radio waves into the valley
Connect a yagi to another yagi (both tuned to GMRS) and direct the second yagi into the valley (akin to a tunnel transmitter, as mentioned in the wikipedia page on passive repeaters)
Joel W1ZR (from QST's The Doctor Is In) suggests a half-wave antenna tuned to the resonant frequency, which avoids any phase shifting by simply reflecting the radio waves.

What is the best way to solve this radio shadow problem?

Is there a not-quite-so-centrally located place for the repeater that hits the valley yet while serving the community better overall?

And, while it might require some further clarification of rules, linking two GMRS repeaters for emergency response only might be tolerated?


How bad is the dead zone? Is it just a few dB short (could it be improved by tweaking the repeater antenna), or is it completely unuseable? 2) is it dead for transmit and receive, with a 5 W handheld and/or a 50 W vehicle radio? 3) How far is the dead zone from the repeater?  4) how far is the dead zone from the nearest "strong zone" where you can easily hear/use the repeater?


@JonCuster, unfortunately we are surrounded by National Forest land, so if we want this to be completely above board, it could be years before we can get the NFS to issue permits for a more advantageous repeater site.  This valley is so deep that even moving the repeater to a site on a nearby mountaintop doesn't fix the coverage problem.

@tomnexus The dead zone is very close to the nearest "strong zone", which is at the top of one of the sides of the valley.  Unfortunately, the walls of the valley are such that the dead zone is not completely eliminated until the repeater has an antenna with 28dBi gain (according to modeling by VE2DBE's radiomobile online, our repeater's antenna is 8dBi)).  Hence why I'm exploring other ways to extend coverage.
